# Define anonymous variable without initialization and use it in switch statement

Tags: c#, .net, types

Is it possible to define an anonymous variable and use it in a `switch` statement?

Something like this:

I need define an `IEnumerable` type to actually loop through entity types in a `DbContext`.

```
DAL.DataClasses1DataContext _db = new DAL.DataClasses1DataContext();
var dbItems;

switch (tableName)
{
     case "QuarryCats" : 
         dbItems = _db.QuarryCats.ToList();
         break;
}

foreach (var item in dbItems)
{
    var orderitem = orderItems.Single(rs => rs.itemId == item.Id);
    item.OrderId = orderitem.orderId;
}

_db.SubmitChanges();
```

Presently I get an compile time error:

> Implicity-Type local variable must initialize

Update: 
my all return types from swich have Id and OrderId fields. need i cast?

Comment: Error states itself, its not possible since var implies type during initialization. You have to initialize it before use.

Comment: `var` does not represent an anonymous type. It is just an implicitly typed variable. That is _not_ the same thing.

Comment: thank you but how define implicity type and initilze in swich statment

Comment: What does _db.QuarryCats.ToList() return?

Comment: _db is DataClasses1DataContext type

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't sure the type of your variable then you can defien it as `dynamic`. But you can't use Intellisense,it's a disadvantage.

```
dynamic myAnonymous;
```

After that you can assign whatever you want your myAnonymous.It will initialize in runtime.

Comment: This is the atomic bomb solution to all type system problems. I would not recommend dynamic in this case.

Comment: tnx but want loop through it

Comment: You can loop through it,just make sure you write your property names correctly

Comment: @usr you'r right but do you have any other solution to do this ?

Comment: @Selman22 I'd statically declare the type or somehow refactor the function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "var" requires that variable type should be defined at *compile time*, e.g.

```
  var myVar = 1 + 5 / 7.8; // <- Compiler can elaborate that myVar is double
```

In you case `myAnonymous`'s type *depends* on `tableName` value - which case will be
executed, - so `myAnonymous`'s type is *run time* defined which is forbidden.

```
  var myAnonymous; // <- Unknown type, can't be elaborated!

  switch (tableName) {
    case "QuarryCats" : 
      myAnonymous = 123; // <- Here it's int

      break;
    case "SomeOther":
      myAnonymous = "ABC"; // <- Here it's String
```

you can, however, use *run time* type definition:

```
  dynamic myAnonymous;

  switch (tableName) {
    case "QuarryCats" : 
      myAnonymous = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable myAnonymous = new object[]{};
```

In loop:

```
foreach(var item in myAnonymous) {
     var cat = item as QuarryCat;
     if(cat != null) {
         cat.property = "something new";
     }
}
```

Or if you have an interface for your types with common fields:

```
IEnumerable<IAnimal> myAnonymous = new IAnimal[]{};
```

In loop:

```
foreach(var animal in myAnonymous) {
    animal.eyeColor = "blue";
}
```

Comment: dear @Hallvar Helleseth, yes it's correct but anther errro ocured! my all Object has OrderId, example: Product and product cat and some other has OrderId . by defining ienumrable<object> Type can loop but can't assign to it's fildes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<object> myAnonymous = new List<object>();

switch (tableName)
{
   case   "QuarryCats" : myAnonymous= _db.QuarryCats.ToList();
   break;
}

foreach (var item in myAnonymous)
{
}
```

Instead of `IEnumerable<object>` if you know the type returned by `_db.QuarryCats.ToList()` use that instead. So if `_db.QuarryCats.ToList()` returns `QuarryCats`, use `IEnumerable<QuarryCats>` .

Answer (score 0):

Although, as other mentioned, it is possible to work around this problem with usage of `dynamic`, I would rather prefer to think about more strong-typed solution. What is important here is that your switch assigns a collection to be later enumerated. And because that is common, I would use it as a type:

```
IList myAnonymous = null;
switch (tableName)
{
   case   "QuarryCats" : myAnonymous = _db.QuarryCats.ToList();
   break;
}
foreach (var item in myAnonymous )
{
   // ..           
}
```

Another thing is that it would be much easier if objects in collection implemented some common interface, so the `myAnonymous` could be a generic collection like `IList<ISomeCommonInterface>`.

In other words, in my opinion, using `var` here makes too much troubles.